# How do I get cookies from a capybara-webkit session?

Tags: ruby, cookies, capybara, capybara-webkit

I have already looked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224001/capybara-cucumber-getting-cookies) and grepped through [the documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Session) for the word `cookie`. However, I am working with legacy code that looks like the following.

```
require 'capybara'
require 'amatch'

Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|                             
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)          
end                                                                   

session = Capybara::Session.new(:chrome)                              
session.visit("http://facebook.com")
```

**How can I pull the cookies out of the `session` object?**

I am using `capybara 2.1.0` and `capybara-webkit 1.1.1`.
Note that I need to use chrome because I need the full JS support that chrome provides for my use case.

The duplicate question contains the solution but the answer is obscured by a lot of content that is not relevant to this question. The duplicate also does not include a reproducible minimum working example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails + Cucumber/Capybara: How to set/retrieve cookies in tests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325960/rails-cucumber-capybara-how-to-set-retrieve-cookies-in-tests)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The duplicate question pointed me in the right direction but it was too noisy and I eventually consulted the docs for [`Selenium::WebDriver::Options`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Options.html) and [`Selenium::WebDriver::Driver`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Driver.html)

The following is how we get cookies out.

```
puts session.driver.browser.manage.all_cookies
```

Comment: This is actually for the Selenium driver and not for capybara-webkit.

Comment: I found this to be a good place to start looking. https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#manipulating-cookies.
`page.driver.cookies` worked for me.